# ugly unwanted vertical lines in density plot

Tags: r, ggplot2

As I am wont to do on Fridays, I'm doing some plotting.

Today's adventure is with some weighted density plots:

```
set.seed(1234)
test <- data.frame(x=rnorm(100), y=rnorm(100))
ggplot() + 
  geom_histogram(data=test, aes(x=x, y=..density.., weight=abs(y)), stat='density')
```

This does what I want, but there are these ugly effing vertical lines going through the plot:

[image: utter crap]
These aren't gridlines, or in my data. If I resize the plot, they still show up, just differently![image: more crap]

How do I get rid of them?

I'm doing it like this so I can make a fancy back-to-back plot:

```
ggplot() + 
 geom_histogram(data=test[test$y>0,], aes(x=x, y=..density.., weight=abs(y)),  stat='density') + 
 geom_histogram(data=test[test$y<0,], aes(x=x, y=-..density.., weight=abs(y)), stat='density')
```

Which gives me this striped slugblob:

[image: ugly striped slugblob]

Here's my session info:

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.0.2 (2013-09-25)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252    LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                          
[5] LC_TIME=English_United States.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] parallel  stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] ggplot2_1.0.0         reshape2_1.2.2        abind_1.4-0           

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] colorspace_1.2-4   dichromat_2.0-0    digest_0.6.4       grid_3.0.2         gtable_0.1.2       labeling_0.2       MASS_7.3-29        munsell_0.4.2      plyr_1.8.1        
[10] proto_0.3-10       RColorBrewer_1.0-5 Rcpp_0.11.1        scales_0.2.3       stringr_0.6.2      tools_3.0.2
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
set.seed(1234)
test <- data.frame(x=rnorm(100), y=rnorm(100))
ggplot(
  data=test,
  aes(x=x,weight=abs(y)))+
geom_density(fill="black")+
geom_density(
  aes(x=x,y=-..density..,weight=abs(y)),
  fill="grey")
##
```

[image]

Comment: i was using geom_histogram so i could do the back-to-back plot. is there a way to do that using geom_density?

Answer (score 0):

Modification to nrussell's code that does exactly what I want:

```
ggplot() + 
 geom_density(data=test[test$y>0,], aes(x=x, y=..density.., weight=abs(y)), fill='black') + 
 geom_density(data=test[test$y<0,], aes(x=x, y=-..density.., weight=abs(y)), fill='black')
```

Yay slugblob without ugly lines!

[image]